# Why someone should really use a setter when a regular variable can do the job?

Tags: dart

Let's say you've a getter-setter like this:

```dart
int _foo;
set foo(int f) => _foo = f;
int get foo => _foo;
```

But the same thing can be done using a regular

```dart
int foo;
```

I don't understand when you'll actually need a setter? Can someone please explain by giving an example?

Comment: If a regular variable really can do the job, I think it's fine. There's lots of uses of setters. Suppose for example your variable is not just an int, it is a special kind of integer, with lots of extra properties. It would be nice to know you could rely on _foo actually having these properties. If you have a setter than you can put custom logic to make sure the right things happen.

Comment: But I think we shouldn't do those tough logic handling (like you mentioned) in a setter. It will just not look good. Setters (in my opinion) aren't meant for those cases. A simple function will be a better choice.

Comment: If you allow people to do blah.foo = whatever, how are you going to prevent invalid ints getting into the foo variable?

Comment: Whether you set some state from a single input via a setter or via a function is mostly a matter of preference.  In many languages, if you need to perform any logic, you don't have a choice: you have to use a function.  Dart gives you a choice.  What do you want your API to look like?  Do you want to perform some logic that appears invisible to callers?  Prefer a setter.  If the logic is complex and time-consuming, a function can make that more obvious to callers.

Comment: @jamesdlin This comes from a Dart developer perspective as to why they did this. Sir, I request you to please write it down as an answer and not just leave it as a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A setter can be used if you have some logic to be executed when a variable is set. A basic example could be the following where you want to track the last time the object was updated:

```
class A {
  int _foo = 42;
  DateTime _lastUpdated = DateTime.now();

  int get foo => _foo;
  set foo(int foo) {
    _foo = foo;
    _lastUpdated = DateTime.now();
  };

  DateTime get lastUpdated => _lastUpdated;
}
```

Another use case would be to make some verification so you e.g. throw an error if you try assign a negative integer.